# SQL SELECT from same tables two times

Tags: sql, select

Whats the best way to select names two times from a table

```
NAME table
Id  Name
1   john
2   zoe
3   joe
4   abby

COUPLE table
NameId NameId2
1      2
3      4
```

Result should look

```
Name  Name
john  zoe
joe   abby
```

I would do something like this

```
SELECT NAME.Name, NAME2.Name 
FROM COUPLE, NAME, NAME AS NAME2 
WHERE NAME.Id=COUPLE.NameId 
AND NAME2.Id=COUPLE.NameId2
```

Is this the best way to get the result? (for performance)

Comment: If it works, then what are you really asking? What needs to be 'better'? Are you running into performance issues?

Comment: Looks like a good homework question in Intro SQL.

Comment: I would use explicit `JOINS` instead of using the non-ANSI standard of lumping them in your `WHERE` statement

Comment: @jp2code the user put in effort to this question, so even if it a homework question, who cares?

Comment: No its not an homework question. I am just interested in performance. But I guess my solution is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My biggest recommendation is to use explicit joins and also scope your second name in the SELECT list

```
SELECT NAME.Name, NAME2.Name Name2
FROM COUPLE
 INNER JOIN NAME ON NAME.Id=COUPLE.NameId 
 INNER JOIN NAME AS NAME2 ON NAME2.Id=COUPLE.NameId2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT n1.Name, n2.Name
FROM Couple C 
JOIN Name n1 ON (n1.id = c.nameID)
JOIN Name n2 ON (n2.id = c.nameID2)
```